# Javascript CharAt method doesnt work for a string

Tags: javascript, string, charat

```
var teksts= (document.getElementById("teksts").value);
letter=document.getElementById("letter").value;
var results = teksts.split(" ");
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = results
var count = new Array
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++)
      {
var first= new String (results[i])    
    for (var j=0; j<first.length; j++)
   {if (first.CharAt(j)==letter)
       {count [i]++}
      }
```

I have this piece of code in Javascript that is supposed to read a string from HTML and a letter and then find which one of the words has the most of this type of letters in it. So i tried to keep it simple, split the string into an array, have each of the array elements defined as a string and then have a loop go through every letter and if it is the letter that is asked for, mark it in count array.

The problem is, even though i specifically define that the word (in variable first) should be a string and then try to use CharAt method for it to get the specific symbol, i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object String] has no method 'CharAt' "

I can't with all my googling skills understand why the method won't work for me.

Comment: The name of the method is `charAt`, not `CharAt`.

Comment: "with all my googling skills", first 10 hits show "charAt". Oh wait, the next ten zillion hits too.

Comment: I think all standard Javascript methods follow that naming style. The first word starts with a small letter, all the other words start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The method name is [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) not `CharAt`, note the small `c`
2. Suggestion 1: `var count = new Array` should have been `var count = [];` Its always better to create empty arrays like this, because `Array` can be anything at runtime as it can be overwritten.
3. Suggestion 2: It is a good practice to mark the end of lines with `;` (semi colon) in javascript.

Comment: #2 should be `var count = [];`. Don't use `new` to create empty arrays or objects, use literals.

Comment: Thank you. It was my fault. I always forget that Javascript is case sensitive so i didn't notice that in google results the method was charAt not CharAt. without you guys pointing it out to me, i would've probably been stuck for a couple of more hours on a simple mistake like this. 

:)